# python fabric3 executing boto3 functionality on remote ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, boto3, fabric

I am trying to execute boto3 functionality from local machine via python fabric3 scripts.

**Configuration on local machine:**

1. installed python3.5 fabric3
2. script using fabric3 to create aws rds snapshot.
3. ssh auth store in `ssh-add ~/.ssh/ec2.pem`

**Configuration on aws EC2 instance:**

1. created ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials ans store required config like:

   ```
     a. region=, output in ~/.aws/config aws_access_key_id=,    
     b. aws_secret_access_key in ~/.aws/credentials
   ```
2. rds is open to ec2 instance only.

**Observation:**

1. while executing fabric script from local machine it ask for `botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.`
2. if I provides region name while in boto3.client(region_name='') 
   it will ask for 
   `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`

***means python fabric doesn't pick up the ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials files.***

**1. Does python fabric pickup the credential & configs from ~/.aws? because I don't want to provides the credential via fabric script**

**2. What is the standard way to achieve the fabric based deployment on aws-ec2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time-being while creating boto3.client() I passed the required `aws_access_key_id` `aws_secret_access_key`, but still problem is that why boto3 client not picking up the .aws/config and .aws/cred files while triggered via Python Fabric script.